# What is the "go" way to checking custom types in go?

Tags: types, go

I was trying to test the exact type of an object (either a costume struct or interface) in golang and was trying to figure out how to do it a way that does *not* real like a cheap hack. (Notice that built in types like strings, ints, floats, slices, etc are not what I am asking about).

Say that I have a Animal interface that implements a Speak method:

```
type Animal interface {
    Speak() string
}
```

and a Dog struct that implements that interface:

```
type Dog struct {
}

func (d Dog) Speak() string {
    return "Woof!"
}
```

say I have some variable x, how do I check what struct type it has and act accordingly?

For example I wanted something like:

```
func isDog(thing Animal{}) bool {
    if reflect.TypeOf(thing) == packageName.Dog{
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

The only solution that I thought of doing was not really what I wanted to do but I guess it works. First create an empty struct of the type I want to check and then use the reflect package to check for equality. Something like:

```
func isDog(thing Interface{}) bool {
    d := Dog{}
    if reflect.TypeOf(thing) == reflect.TypeOf(d){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

The reason I didn't really like that is, say I have a larger code that I need a switch statement eventually. Then, I have to write so much extra code that I feel is unnecessary, like, I need to create the number of many empty struct types as I have cases. It seems unnecessary and really ugly. Is that the only way to do it? I also wanted it to be flexible enough to me it check for pointers too. Something like:

```
func isDog(thing Interface{}) bool {
    d := Dog{}
    if reflect.TypeOf(thing) == packageName.Dog{
        return true
    }else if reflect.TypeOf(thing) == *packageName.Dog{
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To determine the dynamic type of an interface variable, you can use the two-return form of a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).  For example, your `isDog` function could be implemented as:

```
func isDog(thing Animal) bool {
    _, isdog := thing.(packageName.Dog)
    _, isdogptr := thig.(*packageName.Dog)
    return isdog || isdogptr
}
```

Comment: That does look exactly like I wanted, but... when I try it, the code throws me a strange error I don't understand. It says `impossible type assertion "github.com/pinocchio/farm/pkgName".Dog does not implement "github.com/pinocchio/farm/pkgName".Animal ` (Speak method has pointer receiver). Strange... I don't understand this, the two things have the exact same methods defined and return the same types, no typos.

Comment: If you have a method like `func (d *Dog) Speak() string`, it will only be in the method set of `*Dog` for the purposes of implementing interfaces, and not `Dog`.  You can not get a pointer to the value stored inside an interface variable, so the method can not be used.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge the thing that confuses me is, why is it crashing? If it cannot be converted to that type, why doesn't it just say so instead of throwing me an error?

Comment: If you have a variable `d` of type `Dog` and call `d.Speak()`, the call is automatically translated to `(&d).Speak()`, since the method takes a pointer as its receiver.  The problem is that you can't take a pointer to the value stored in an interface variable, so the method is not considered to be part of `Dog`'s method set.  Since this means that `Dog` doesn't implement the `Animal` interface, the type assertion could never pass so the compiler treats it as an error.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way is to use a [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) rather than type assertions directly.

```
func isDog(animal Animal) bool {
    switch animal.(type) {
    case Dog:
    case *Dog:
    default:
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I think blank identifier misuse and `myVariable || randomIdent` in this context is gross.